# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() Return null on Edge Chromium

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-edge

Today i start to recive GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() null if i use edge chromium.
Maby Microsoft change something in cookie policy,... i don´t know.

It works yesterday, buy today no. this is the code:

```
 var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); //returns allways null in edge
```

Desen´t work any more in Microsoft Edge.

I use fiddler to check and i see that using edge no request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me (this endpoint giveme GetExternalLoginInfoAsync) and using chrome there are the request!... why????

Comment: Which version of Edge and OS are you using? Which version of .net-core are you using? Have you tested in Chrome to see if the issue still persists?

Comment: Edge: Version 97.0.1072.55, .netcore 5

Comment: In chrome works! its like it was an update on edge chromium this days...

Comment: I made a sample to test according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and using sample code from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/social/additional-claims/samples/3.x/ClaimsSample). It works well in my Edge which version is the same as yours. I can get user's login info from `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()`. Could you please disable all the extensions in your Edge and test again in **InPrivate mode**?

Comment: Private mode it works. i allso clear all the cookies. This is not only in my machine but a lot of them

Comment: If in InPrivate mode it works, then it means that the method can work in Edge. I think the issue is related to some Edge settings or policies configured. Are the machines having the problem in your company? In general, machines in a company are controlled by domain. Then there might be the domain changed some settings or policies related to Edge. You can try to disable all Edge add-ons, clear all browser data, and reset Edge then test again. Besides, you can navigate to *edge://policy/* to check if there're related policies applied which might lead to the issue.

Comment: Was what i thought, policies by domain. My computer in home work well. But fanny thing is the edge don´t have nothing in policies.

Comment: In InPrivate mode it usually doesn't enable Edge add-ons and doesn't store any browser data. 

You can check if there's any add-on enabled in normal mode which leads to the issue. Besides, you can add a new Edge profile, clear all browser data by navigating to *edge://settings/clearBrowserData* and test again with that new profile.

Comment: I found the issue. Is on service worker (PWA). If i unregister, when i return to webpage it works. If i follow this path: 1º Logout, 2º Login again using office 365, 3º the signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() will return null (it's like service worker is doing something here). If i do the same,  1º Logout, 2º unregister service worker via devtools, 3º login office 365, Done! Works! any ideia why? only in Edge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Is on service worker (PWA). If i unregister, when i return to webpage it works.

**If i follow this path (dosen't work):**

1º Logout

2º Login again using office 365

3º the signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() will return null (it's like service worker is doing something here).

**If i this it works:**

1º Logout

2º Unregister service worker via devtools

3º Login office 365, Done! Works!

Any ideia why? only in Microsoft Edge!